# I can't sign in to Instagram

Tags: account-management, instagram

I have just started up an Instagram account about a month ago but I haven't been able to sign in. It keeps saying it's the wrong password and email. What can I do as I want to use the Instagram app?

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong email id or password or both. If you are sure that you are using correct email id then you can reset the password.

Instagram allows to [reset passwords](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/) in following 3 ways:

- **Reset using Email or Username:** In this you should have the access of your email id connected to you account.
- **Reset using SMS:** In this, you can get reset link in your SMS and using that you can reset your password.
- **Reset using Facebook:** In this, you can use facebook login to reset your password.

According to [Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/409847499070242):

> To reset your password, first tap **Forgot**? next to **Password** on the log in screen.
>
> - To reset through your email address, tap **Username or Email**, enter your username or the email address you used to create your account and tap search. Choose **Send a Password Reset Email**.
>
> If you can't access the email you registered with and you didn't link your Instagram account to Facebook, we're not able to give you access to this account.